# Speed up a post request for every row in pandas DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Suppose i have following dataframe

```
| id | info       | cost |

| 1 | some string | 123 |
```

The whole `shape` of dataframe is `13534` rows. For every row i need to make a `post request`, something like

```
{'id': 1, 'info': 'some string', 'cost': 123}
```

Using a for loops will be slow. Is there any way to speed up this process? Maybe `threading`? Does any body got a good example to tackle this task using `threading`?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need each POST request to complete before moving on to the next row for any reason or is each row independent from every other row?

Based on your response that the rows can be processed independently, you can use a threaded approach, although for a lot of Input/Output operations you may find that async programming will maximize the utilization for a thread regardless of how many threads you use. The built-in package `asyncio` or a third-party library such as `aiohttp` may be appropriate for your use-case. Without knowing more, it is difficult to comment. For threading, since you are only reading from the dataframe, you do not need to use any locks, semaphores, etc as there is no risk of race condition, you will see further gains by using @nk03 's suggestion to use `df.to_dict('records')`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, they can be independent

Answer (score 0):

Use [`to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
result = df.to_dict('records')
```

OUTPUT:

```
[{'id': 1, 'info': 'some string', 'cost': 123}]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. They main idea of question how to speed up post request for every row in dataframe

Comment: Iterating over a dict is much faster as compare to iterating over a large df. @AlexNikitin

Comment: yes, you are right, thank you